# How to match a repeated boolean search string pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm attempting to build a regex to match all the bits of a boolean search. I'm able to get close, but end up skipping some matches. Here's what i've got so far.

String to check:

"foo AND bar OR baz AND whatever"

Here's what I've got so far (I know, I'm missing some characters like quotes, parens, etc.):

```
(\w+)(?:.(AND|OR|NOT).(\w+))
```

Current Outcome:

```
[
  "foo AND bar",
  "foo",
  "AND",
  "bar",
]
[
  "baz AND whatever",
  "baz",
  "AND",
  "whatever"
]
```

Notice I'm missing the "bar AND baz" portion. By adding a + to the end of the regex it matches the entire string, but it seems to ignore some of the capturing groups after the first word group and then capture the final bit (hope that makes sense).

Desired Outcome:

```
[
  "foo AND bar OR baz AND whatever",
  "foo",
  "AND",
  "bar",
  "OR",
  "baz",
  "AND",
  "whatever"
]
```

OR

```
[
  "foo AND bar",
  "foo"
  "AND"
  "bar"
]
[
  "bar OR baz",
  "bar",
  "OR",
  "baz"
]
[
  "baz AND whatever",
  "baz",
  "AND",
  "whatever"
]
```

The first desired outcome would be preferable I think. So, what am I missing here? I'm pretty sure I need a back reference to capturing group #3 but can't seem to get that to work.

Comment: why not split by the known operators?

Comment: Mainly for brevity. I'm trying to stay away from having to create multiple parsers and this seems the best way to go. Also, more conditions will be added as this goes along (i.e. "this and (that or theOtherThing) not somethingElse"). And it just seems easier to do that as a regex instead of multiple parsers.